# ErrorHandler issue Migrating from PHP 5.5 to 7

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu-16.04

I'm working on migrating from Ubuntu 14 to 16 and php 5.5 to 7.  When I'm trying to turn on my application, I keep running into an ErrorHandler Fatal Error.  Does anyone know a quick way to resolve this?

```
ubuntu@dev2:/var/www/xyz$ php app/console
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler::handleException() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given in /var/www/xyz/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/ErrorHandler.php:436
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(Error))
#1 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/xyz/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/ErrorHandler.php on line 436
```

Comment: What's the symfony version you are using?

Comment: Symfony version is 2.6.3